# How to bind data from service in Kendo Scheduler from local server

Tags: angularjs, kendo-scheduler, kendo-datasource

I'm using kendo UI scheduler in my application to make various reservation for different rooms. I'm able to bind the data to the scheduler on the init function.

The next requirement is when I click a skip button it skips a particular number of days and the same API is called retrieving different set of data for that date range.

I'm getting this data in my 'vm' object but the data is not showing up in the scheduler. When I asked the Telerik support the asked me to implement setDataSource() but it shows error in my application

[image: Error on providing setDataSource()]
[Example for binding data](https://dojo.telerik.com/@nithin@amt.in/EHaDEbUP)

[Example shown from telerik](https://dojo.telerik.com/@nithin@amt.in/uYuRuHEj)

Comment: You need to post some of your code so we can try to find the problem. Alternatively, you can try the following: After the page has loaded, open dev tools and check the `Pause on caught exceptions` box. when you see the same exception, go down the call tree and see where in your code the problem was initiated.

Comment: @Shai thanks for dropping in the comment but I have identified how the error was generated. The setDataSource() was somehow conflicting with the telerik report files in my app. after removing the file it started working fine.